# Is there a built-in for "circle function"?

Tags: functions, special-functions, fourier-analysis

Is there a built-in function in Mathematica for this function?

\begin{equation}
{\displaystyle \operatorname {Circ} (r)=\left\{{\begin{array}{rl}1,&{\text{if }}r<{1}\\{\frac {1}{2}},&{\text{if }}r={1}\\0,&{\text{if }}r>{1}.\end{array}}\right.}
 \end{equation}
where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

I use:

`UnitBox[1/2*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]`

and the function is equivalent, but Mathematica doesn't do the Fourier transform in my system (MMA v. 11.0).

Comment: `FourierTransform[UnitBox[1/2*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, y}, {u, v}]` returns a result on my machine.

Comment: MMA version 12.1 on PC returns: 1/2 Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, 1/4 (-u^2 - v^2)]

Comment: well, my computer is simple, maybe because of this he doesn´t do the transform, my wolfram version is 11.0

Comment: the fourier transform of circ is a bessel function J1(2*Pi*r)/r

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)
```

The functions are equivalent for integration but they have different values for `r == 1`. Use [`PiecewiseExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html) to convert the expression

```
Assuming[Element[{x, y}, Reals],
 UnitBox[1/2*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] // PiecewiseExpand]
```

[image]

```
Assuming[Element[{x, y}, Reals],
 FourierTransform[
  UnitBox[1/2*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] // PiecewiseExpand, {x, y}, {u, v}]]
```

[image]

```
% // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain a result in terms of Bessel functions using [`FunctionExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html):

```
FunctionExpand@
 FourierTransform[UnitBox[1/2*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, y}, {u, v}]

(* Out: BesselI[1, Sqrt[-u^2 - v^2]]/Sqrt[-u^2 - v^2] *)
```